# tomcat localhost url return ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

I developed a spring MVC app in eclipse and trying to test in my laptop tomcat localhost. This URL works http://localhost:8080. It brings up the tomcat admin page. But when i call http://localhost:8080/mywebsite, as part of spring security port mapping it forwards to https://localhost:8443/mywebsite, but i get

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

1. This is definitely not firewall issue, as i uninstalled all my antivirus, disabled firewall in windows defender
2. I have also changed the server location to "use tomcat installation" in eclipse
3. I have cleaned up deployment folder multiple times and reinstalled app and restarted server multiple times. The server started successfully i can see the logs
4. I am using tomcat 9 and JDK-19
5. I dont see any calls in access logs, only a 302 when it redirects from http://localhost:8080/mywebsite to https://localhost:8443/mywebsite

I have been trying this for 2 days and it wont budge an inch. I need help please

Comment: Have you configured a SSL/TLS Connector on port 8443 in your Tomcat's `server.xml` file? Otherwise of course it's not listening there.

Answer (score 0):

As @nitin pointed out in the comment above, I had not configured SSL connector. My bad I thought SSl cert is not needed for localhost testing. But it is required. I following the steps in
https://medium.com/beingcoders/setup-ssl-on-apache-tomcat-in-just-10-minutes-step-by-step-guide-706484094bb2